# How to get MIN MAX used nagios perf data with rrdtool command?

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios, rrdtool

I need to get the rrdtool MIN and MAX perf data from all the service. Unable to use pnp4nagios and xport for all the services. How can I get the MIN and MAX perf data with rrdtool fetch command?

Used below command give many lines

`rrdtool fetch /usr/local/pnp4nagios/var/perfdata/server1/nrdp-Current_Load.rrd MIN -r 300 -s -1days -e now | head -n5`

But it gives below output

`1549296600: 2.6540000000e+00 2.9740000000e+00 3.0300000000e+00
 1549296900: 2.5040000000e+00 2.8420000000e+00 2.9700000000e+00
 1549297200: 2.8100000000e+00 2.8820000000e+00 2.9620000000e+00`

What is the single command to get both Ex,984(LAST) and 2806(MAX) values which is from pnp4nagios?